# Запятая при деепричастии

Tags: запятая

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить запятые в предложении:

> Но я уверен, что необходимо развивать
> профориентацию начиная со школьной
> скамьи, чтобы...

Меня интересует, нужна ли запятая перед словом начиная. Я думаю, что не нужна. Спасибо.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, это как раз тот случай, когда деепричастие утрачивает глагольное значение. Сочетания НАЧИНАЯ С (в знач "с такого-то времени"), ИСХОДЯ ИЗ  ("на основании"), СМОТРЯ ПО ("в соответствии") и некот. др. выступают в роли сложных предлогов и не обособляются, если их можно опустить без ущерба для смысла предложения.

Попробуем опустить: Но я уверен, что необходимо развивать профориентацию со школьной скамьи, чтобы...  - всё нормально, значит, запятые не нужны.

Comment: Вернее, одна запятая, вторая отделяет придаточное

Answer (score 0):

> Но я уверен, что необходимо развивать
> профориентацию начиная со школьной
> скамьи, чтобы...

Запятая нужна. Но лучше, по-моему, убрать деепричастие:

*Но я уверен, что необходимо развивать профориентацию со школьной скамьи, чтобы...*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Ваши ответы мне очень помогают.